# How to reference GmailApp in a js file other than Code.gs?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to reference `GmailApp` in a `my_custom_js.html` file, as opposed to the `Code.gs` file?

The following works when used in `Code.gs`:

```
// BEGIN email
// define email recipients
var email_recipient = uploader_email;
// Email subject
var subject = "Form submitted"
// Email body
var body = my_html; 
Logger.log(email_recipient);    
// Send email
GmailApp.sendEmail(email_recipient, subject, body);
// END email
```

But it doesn't work when used in a function in `my_custom_js.html`.

`Developer Tools` > `Console` shows error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Logger is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined
```

The reason I want it to run in the custom script, is that it utilises:

```
// BEGIN handle form submit
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
}
// END handle form submit
```

And, if I understand that code correctly, `updateUrl` is only running after a successful operation - so I'd like to send the email from the `updateUrl()` function (ie after a successful operation).

Perhaps I need to use something like a [scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) , but for use in js files?

**Edit**

I'm looking into:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

And will see if I can pass through the values to a function defined in `Code.gs` using the following in `my_custom_js.html`:

```
google.script.run.sendNotificationEmail(arg1,arg2);
```

**Edit**

That last idea worked, but would appreciate any insight on the original question, thanks.

Comment: To print something to the browser console from an HTML `<script>` tag use `console.log('something')` instead of `Logger.log('something')`  You could have a scriptlet that does anything you want.  The scriptlet could send an email before the HTML is served.  The success handler could make a second `google.script.run.functionName()` call to send the email.  An email can not be sent directly from client side code in HTML.  Ultimately the email must be sent from server code in a `.gs` file.

Answer (score 0):

This week for the first time I have been using Google's realatively new [Javascript Client API.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js)  Using this api you could trigger your Google apps script to run from any custom website and get a callback with the result from any methods you would normally use with in the appscript. It took a bit of fiddling to get it to work, including setting up things in API console, but it's so cool you can run and call and trigger any appscript from anywhere.